# Parsing Nested XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

Here's what the XML might look like:

```
<gzoltar>
  <Alaming>
    <suspect>
      <method>alive()</method>
      <line>15</line>
      <score>0.5872202195147035</score>
      <most>no</most>
    </suspect>
    <suspect>
      <method>size()</method>
      <line>127</line>
      <score>0.545544725589981</score>
      <most>no</most>
    </suspect>
  </Alaming>
  <Nephis>
    <suspect>
      <method>fifty()</method>
      <line>41</line>
      <score>0.4016632088371218</score>
      <most>no</most>
    </suspect>
  </Nephis>
<gzoltar>
```

What I want to do is read the innermost entries (the suspect tags) and store the information for each one in multiple variables using something like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;
documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = null;
document = documentBuilder.parse(file);

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("suspect");

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    String method = document.getElementsByTagName("method").item(0).getTextContent();
    String line = document.getElementsByTagName("line").item(0).getTextContent();
    String score = document.getElementsByTagName("score").item(0).getTextContent();
    String most = document.getElementsByTagName("most").item(0).getTextContent();
}
```

However, I also want to, for each suspect, store the information from the two containing tags. For example, the reference for the very first suspect in the example would store "Alaming" and "gzoltar". In the last suspect it would store "Nephis" and "gzoltar" in addition to storing the information from the four tags within itself.

I have not way of knowing what these tags will be (they won't be "Alaming" or "gzoltar"). The only thing I know for sure is that the innermost ones (suspect, method, line, score, and most) will be in that format.

Any suggestions on how to handle this? I'm completely new to reading XML in Java so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: suppose you cam use SAX parser and try. this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) would be good place to start.

Comment: Use [getParentNode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getParentNode()) to reach the containing element, and use [getNodeName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeName()) to get the name of the element. (and get the parent node of the parent node to go two levels up). That's the simplest way.

Comment: Inside your loop, you should never call `document.getElementsByTagName`.  Instead, you should call `getElementsByTagName` on each Element contained in `nList`.

Comment: @VGR Something like this?


`Element e = (Element) node;`

`method = e.getElementsByTagName("method").item(0).getTextContent();`

Comment: Yes, pretty much like that.

Comment: Alright I think I've gotten the hang of it. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You might not be using the best tools. Many people use DOM because they feel it is somehow "standard", but there are much better tree models available in the Java world, for example JDOM2 and XOM. And whichever tree model you use, you might be better off doing most of the navigation around the tree using XPath. And then: do you need Java at all? Could it all be written in a language that was designed for XML processing, like XSLT or XQuery?